# problems in using $.post method

Tags: jquery, python

I have a simple python script which interacts with an API in the following way:

```
RUN_URL = u'https://api.hackerearth.com/v3/code/run/'
CLIENT_SECRET = '***'
source = "print 'Hello World'"

data = {
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
    'async': 0,
    'source': source,
    'lang': "PYTHON",
    'time_limit': 10,
    'memory_limit': 262144,
}
r = requests.post(RUN_URL, data=data)
print r.json()
```

However when trying to achieve same effects using jquery post method, I dont get a response at all

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Random</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
var RUN_URL = "https://api.hackerearth.com/v3/code/run/"
var CLIENT_SECRET = "***"
var source = "print 'Hello World'"
var data = {
    client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    async: 0,
    source: source,
    lang: "PYTHON",
    time_limit: 5,
    memory_limit: 262144,
}
$.post(RUN_URL, data, function (result) {
     alert(result);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot understand where I am going wrong and I have tried every possible thing I could think of.

PS : pretty new to front end

Comment: Since it is a cross domain request - [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy), the problem is said API does not support [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Also it doesn't looks to be supporting jsonp... so you may not be able to use the api directly from the browser(via javascript)... you will need to sent the request to your server from browser which can make the request to the api and return the result from the api call back to the browser